# An issue when checking on PageSpeed Insights

Tags: website

I have an issue when I am checking the website speed on https://developers.google.com

The desktop result appears as below:

Lighthouse returned error: generic::internal: APP::1: Abnormal renderer termination, status = crashed exit_code = 1

Comment: What browser do you use? When I use PageSpeed Insight --> https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2F - it seems to work just fine.. using Chrome Browser.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome. I can see other websites results. Also, need to mention that I can see the Mobile result for my website. The problem in Desktop result, it gives me the code I wrote above. Please try it yourself you may find somethig to determine the problem. https://www.itqantrip.com